# react native fetch not calling then or catch

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am using fetch to make some API calls in react-native, sometimes randomly the fetch does not fire requests to server and my then or except blocks are not called. This happens randomly, I think there might be a race condition or something similar. After failing requests once like this, the requests to same API never get fired till I reload the app. Any ideas how to trace reason behind this. The code I used is below.

```js
const host = liveBaseHost;
const url = `${host}${route}?observer_id=${user._id}`;
let options = Object.assign({
        method: verb
    }, params
    ? {
        body: JSON.stringify(params)
    }
    : null);
options.headers = NimbusApi.headers(user)
return fetch(url, options).then(resp => {
    let json = resp.json();
    if (resp.ok) {
        return json
    }
    return json.then(err => {
        throw err
    });
}).then(json => json);
```

Comment: try adding catch block like this: .catch(error => error)

Comment: Is it happen only when debugging in Chrome ? If so, I might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679). Try adding `setTimeout(() => null, 0);` before `resp.json()`.

Comment: @ncuillery thank you for your response, it is not happening only in chrome, it happens in test builds of app as well. I have seen the issue you have mentioned, but mine was a little bit different. In that issue the resp,json() method blocks but in my case, the then block is never executed, even though the fetch method is called multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

Fetch might be throwing an error and you have not added the catch block. Try this:

```js
return fetch(url, options)
  .then((resp) => {
    if (resp.ok) {
      return resp.json()
        .then((responseData) => {
          return responseData;
        });
    }
    return resp.json()
      .then((error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {/* catch the error here */});
```

Remember that Promises usually have this format:

```js
promise(params)
  .then(resp => { /* This callback is called is promise is resolved */ },
        cause => {/* This callback is called if primise is rejected */})
  .catch(error => { /* This callback is called if an unmanaged error is thrown */ });
```

I'm using it in this way because I faced the same problem before.

Let me know if it helps to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I return the promise from this method and in another method calling this I have a catch block, which is never executed.

Comment: did you try to debug it to see where the error is being thrown (or to see where it is stopping)? Did you see any error in the console (attach them if you have)?

Comment: I do not see any error being thrown and no error in console, it is very weird.

Comment: It is very extrange for me the last _then_ you have used: `.then(json => json)`.  There you are not returning anything, so if there is something waiting for that result, it will never come.
Did you try to implement the code I provided?

Comment: Since i am returning the promise here, I have a catch block where I call this method, I have also tried to add a catch block here as well.

Comment: I have the same problem with OP and in my case this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `fetch` in a try-catch:

```
let res;
try {
    res = fetch();
} catch(err) {
    console.error('err.message:', err.message);
}
```

If you are seeing "network failure error" it is either CORS or the really funny one, but it got me in the past, check that you are not in Airplane Mode.

Comment: I have the same problem with OP and in my case this did not solve the problem

Comment: @Mr.Kro it might be caching due to debug mode. Try disconnecting from remote debugging, and restarting the app. Even re-building the app after cleaning (ie: on mac, xcode clean, then build).

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck into this too, api call is neither going into then nor into catch. Make sure your phone and development code is connected to same Internet network, That worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The cause was that I had extra logging like `console.log('response', response)`, but React Native / Metro / Expo wasn't able to show the logs in the console because of some error. Changing my logging code to `console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response))` let me see what was going on.