# React Native fetch won't execute

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch-api

I've spent several hours trying to figure out how to query an API using fetch, but I can't even seem to get the fetch command to execute.

I'm very new to JavaScript so hopefully someone can just point out some dumb mistake because I can't even get past the first step of using fetch.

Here is the very small snippet of code that I can't get to work:

```
var req = new Request('http://myapp.com:8000/api/posts', {method: 'GET'});
console.log("1");
fetch(req).then(function(res) {
    console.log("2");
    return res.json();
    })
console.log("3");
```

The console logs "1", and "3", every time, but "2" is never even logged.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Also, I am making fetch requests to a locally running Django server, and from monitoring the the server no requests are even being made to the server when I run my react-native app.

Comment: what is function(res)?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using fetch directly, see how it is done on the [Networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) page:

```
var url = 'http://myapp.com:8000/api/posts';
console.log("1");
fetch(url).then(function(res) {
    console.log("2");
    return res.json();
    })
console.log("3");
```

Comment: I have the same problem with OP and in my case this did not solve the problem

Comment: Please post a question and add relevant code, it will be easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can fetch data

```
 fetch("http://date.jsontest.com/")
 console.log("1");
  .then((response) => response.json())

  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log("2");
    this.setState({date: responseData.date});
  })
  .done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a catch to check if there is any error.

```
fetch(url).then(function(res) {
    console.log("2");
    return res.json();
}).catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem with OP and in my case this did not solve the problem. Also, the line `console.error(error)` was never executed too. Another person facing this problem is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467252/react-native-fetch-not-calling-then-or-catch)